# Changing "post_max_size" has no effect

Tags: php, apache, ispconfig

I'm using ISPConfig 3.

I have set:

- `post_max_size` *and* `upload_max_filesize = 10M` in /etc/php5/fpm/php.ini
- `php_value post_max_size` *and* `upload_max_filesize 10M` in .htaccess

Then restarted apache with `/etc/init.d/apache2 restart`

Still, those values are 2M in `phpinfo()`

Comment: `php-fpm restart` - you change php config, so restart php instead of apache

Comment: That did the trick. If you post an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`php-fpm restart` - you change php config, so restart php instead of apache